# How do I save an image into a database using Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I want to save an image into the MySQL database. Following are the error messages when I'm trying to store an image into the database by using [Spring MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Model-view-controller_framework) and Hibernate.

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>   WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

I am using the following set of code:

#### In JSP

```
<form:form action="saveproduct" method="post" modelAttribute="product"
           enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:hidden path="code" />
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name:</td>
        <td><form:input type="text" path="name"  placeholder="ProductName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Price:</td>
        <td><form:input type="text" path="price" placeholder="price"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>
        <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productImage?
        code=${product.code}" width="100"/></td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Upload Image:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

#### In Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void productimage(@RequestParam("code")int code, Model model,
                         HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
IOException
{
    Product product = null;
    if(code != 0)
    {
        product = productdao.findProduct(code);
    }
    if(product != null && product.getProimage() != null)
    {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        response.getOutputStream().write(product.getProimage());
    }
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newproduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newProduct()
{
    Product product = new Product();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("product", product);
    model.setViewName("NewProduct");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/saveproduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product")Product

product,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    try{
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Blob blob = null;
        byte[] contents = file.getBytes();
        blob = new SerialBlob(contents);
        product.setProimage(contents);
        productdao.saveimage(product,file);

        return "admin";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("erorr is "+e);
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

#### Product.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int code;

@Lob
@Column(name="pro_image")
public byte[] proimage;

@Column(name="pro_name")
public String name;

@Column(name="pro_price")
public double price;

// Getter and setter
```

#### In Applicationconfig

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException{
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new
    CommonsMultipartResolver();

    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);

    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```